# How do I display information in my second activity in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

this is my first attempt at programming for Android.
Ive been working on creating an activity which has a list of countries, and once any of them are clicked, a new activity is opened with information regarding that country.

I am trying to use the intent function to do this, I have all the information I want in different arrays, all in the correct order, but my problem seems to be with the "position" function to be able to display them.

This is my MainActivity code regarding the intent:

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] CountryArray = {"Egypt", "Jordan", "Kuwait", "Saudi Arabia"};     


    setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, CountryArray));


    final ListView CountryList = getListView();

    CountryList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {


            final String Country = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra(Country, position);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
```

and this is the code in my second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    String[] CountryArray = {"Egypt", "Jordan", "Kuwait", "Saudi Arabia"};     
    String[] CapitalArray = {"Cairo", "Amman", "Kuwait City", "Riyadh"};
    String[] CurrencyArray = {"EGP", "Jordanian Dinar", "Kuwait Dinar", "Riyal"};
    String[] PopulationlArray = {"90 Million", "6.3 Million", "3.25 Million", "29 Million"};

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getIntExtra("Country", 0);
```

Comment: What is this doing or not doing that you expect?

Comment: Well, when i run it, after clicking on any of the countries, it takes me to the second activity but does not display any of the information

Comment: Yes, what are you expecting? Just a comment: the position of the first element in the list is 0, not 1, the second value is 1 and so on.

Comment: Your second activity (or at least the portion you have shown us) has no code which would display the information you are retrieving.

Comment: @Takendarkk how do i make the second activity display the information in the string? this is the problem i am facing

Comment: Do you have somewhere you want to display it? A View of some kind?

Comment: @Ondkloss i want to display it in the secondactivity, there is a textview in the xml for that second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab the View that you wish to display the information in. If you have a TextView defined in the XML for your second activity this can be done by:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView); // Using ID you set in XML
textView.setText("My information"); // Display your information
```

I'm guessing you would probably set the text to something like `CountryArray[position]`.

Comment: after adding this, when i ran the code, all countries opened gave me the text "Egypt", when i added 4 more textviews, All countries opened gave me the text "90 million" .I still cant seem to be able to display all 4 pieces of information extracted from the strings depending on the position.

Comment: If you want to display several pieces of information you just have to concatenate the information. For example: `textView.setText("Country: "+CountryArray[position]+". Capital: "+CapitalArray[position]+"...");`.

Comment: concatenation worked, all 4 information display when i click. the problem is all 4 countries give me the information about Egypt, the first country, disregarding that their position is supposed to display other information when clicked, i am not able to tackle this

Comment: Then there is something wrong with transfering what list item you click. If you change to `int position = i.getIntExtra("Country", -1)`, does the app crash when you click a list item? (the number is the default value, if it doesn't find one that has been attached as an extra)

Comment: yes, changing it to -1 just crashed it, what does this mean? where is it going wrong with getting the position on the list

Comment: i just changed it from i.getIntExtra("Country", 0) to i.getIntExtra("Country", 1), and it got me the information of the second item in the array when i click on any of them

Comment: Do you have `CountryList.setOnItemClickListener` inside `public void onItemClick`? What is the the `onItemClick` for? The number you are changing is just the default value, if it doesn't find anything attached (so sending the number failed).

Comment: check the code in the question, i edited it and added the whole code, maybe you will be able to spot the mistake as my eyes have been looking at this code for hours

Comment: You are doing `CountryList.setOnItemClickListener` two times (and one inside the other). You should only do it one time. Remove the one inside, and move the intent-code to the first one.

Comment: done, changed it in the main question aswell. but still not working unfortunately. it still displays information for position 0 to all of them

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer about the original question, as your problem is now sending information from one Activity to another through Extras. We like to keep questions and comments on topic here at StackOverflow. The last thing I can see now is that you your line `myIntent.putExtra(Country, position);` is now wrong and should be `myIntent.putExtra("Country", position);`. I hope you are able to fix it! Don't hesitate to ask another question about any new problems you have.